# Join twice on the same ForeignKey

Tags: sql-server, node.js, express, sequelize.js

Im using Sequelize for my Querys.
Everything is going fine except for one Case.
I want this

```
  return db.sequelize.query(`
    SELECT k.name as Name,
    k._id as _id,
    k.notice as notice,
    dv1.value as value1,
    dv2.value as value2,
    dv2._id as v_id
    FROM dict_Keys k
    LEFT JOIN dict_Values dv1 ON k._id=dv1.key_id and dv1.lang_id=` + req.params.id + `
    LEFT JOIN dict_Values dv2 ON k._id=dv2.key_id and dv2.lang_id=` + req.params.id2 + ``, {
      type: Sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT
    })
    .then(handleEntityNotFound(res))
    .then(respondWithResult(res))
    .catch(handleError(res));
```

translate in the ORM Model.

But I couldnt find how to reference twice on the same ForeignKey.

Things as including Model twice is throwing Error, cant include the same Model just twice.

Declaring the second Model with an Alias needs then to create the same Foreignkey twice but named different, that is not wanted!

Is there a Solution in Sequelize for that or at the moment only to declare the ForeignKey twice ?

**EDIT1:**
The ForeignKey Connection

```
 db.DictKey.hasMany(db.DictValue, {
      foreignKey: 'key_id'
    });
```

Try to Include it twice on same ForeignKey

```
export function showAll(req, res) {
  return DictKey.findAll({
    include:[{
      model: DictValue,
      where:{
        lang_id: req.params.id
      }
    },
    {
      model: DictValue,
      where:{
        lang_id: req.params.id
      }
    }
  ]
    })
    .then(handleEntityNotFound(res))
    .then(respondWithResult(res))
    .catch(handleError(res));
}
```

Errors The Correlation name 'dict_Values' is specified multiple times in a From clause.
Assign it twice

```
db.DictValue.belongsTo(db.DictKey,{
  as: 'lang1',
  foreignKey: 'key_id'
});
db.DictValue.belongsTo(db.DictKey,{
  as: 'lang2',
  foreignKey: 'key_id'
});
```

Something like this I tried as well,but dont remember exact, but it generated 2 ForeignKeys which is not wished.

Comment: The way you currently query your database is prone to [SQL injection attacks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection), you can fix that by using [replacements in sequelize.js](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/raw-queries/#replacements).

Comment: If I could do something like findAll()...include same model twice on same foreignkey. I would not even need replacements. That is the question here. I dont want to use sequelize.query at all

Comment: Please show the code that you used when you tried it with include, especially how you tried to express the condition.

Comment: Edited a few Infos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is to set Aliases for the Keys.
My fault was to do it in the `belongsTo` Association.
It has to be in the `hasMany` Association.

```
db.DictKey.hasMany(db.DictValue, {
  foreignKey: 'key_id',
  as : 'value1'
});
db.DictValue.belongsTo(db.DictKey,{
  foreignKey : 'key_id',
});
db.DictKey.hasMany(db.DictValue, {
  foreignKey: 'key_id',
  as : 'value2'
});
db.DictValue.belongsTo(db.DictKey,{
  foreignKey : 'key_id',
});
```